# changing a text file based on another textile using awk

Tags: string, awk

I have a text file which starts which contains a set of random numbers. In a second file another set of random numbers which includes the numbers from the first file. I need to do an edit whenever these numbers match.

file b

```
1
5
7
9
```

file a

```
1 100 100 100
4 100 100 100
5 100 100 100
7 100 100 100
8 100 100 100
9 100 100 100
11 100 100 100
12 100 100 100
```

output

```
1 10000 10000 10000
4 100 100 100
5 10000 10000 10000
7 10000 10000 10000
8 100 100 100
9 10000 10000 10000
11 100 100 100
12 100 100 100
```

I tried the following:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;next} {    
    while(getline && end=="") {
        if (a[FNR]==$1){
            end=1;
            print $1, $2,"00", $3,"00",$4,"00"
        }else{
            print $1, $2, $3, $4
        }
    }         
}' b.inp a.inp > new.inp
```

however I try my code rolls one line in both files when I use getline. Therefore I can never make a match. I need it to only roll lines in the second file, while I use the loop.
Any helps will be appreciated!

Comment: Read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline if you're ever considering using getline in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk reads your file(s) line by line automatically, so it's not necessary to call `getline`.

Just save the keys from `fileb` in an array, then multiply the second to last column values by 100 when the first column of `filea` matches:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { lines[$0]; next } 
$1 in lines { for (col = 2; col <= NF; ++col) $col *= 100 } 1' fileb filea
```

Answer (score 2):

COuld you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk  'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} ($1 in a){for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){$i="10000"}} 1' fileb filea
```

***OR***

```
awk  'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} ($1 in a){for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){$i=$i*100}} 1' fileb filea
```

Seems OP's Input_file(s) could have control M characters in them so could you please check once `cat -v filea` and `cat -v fileb`? If yes then remove them by doing `tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file`

Comment: It just matches 9.

Comment: @RaymondGhaffarianShirazi, Could you please check once `cat -v filea` and `cat -v fileb`? Seems your files may be carriage returns? If yes then remove them by doing `tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` Kindly check and let me know then?

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can use getline. It will actually save the unnecessary if statement for the second file (if you care about this small performance change).

```
awk 'BEGIN{while( getline line<"fileb" ) {a[line]} 
($1 in a) { for (col = 2; col <= NF; ++col) $col *= 100 } 1' filea
```

Comment: That is not how to use getline and use of getline is the wrong approach for this type of problem. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.